# VirtualBox 64-bit guest

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, 64-bit, virtualization

I'm trying to install Ubuntu (64 bit) as a guest operating system in VirtualBox. My setup is an Intel i3 machine with Windows 7 (64 bit) and VirtualBox 4.3.4r91027 (latest version). I went through the setup wizard to create a new virtual machine, but when I try to boot Ubuntu it complains that it doesn't have an x64 CPU.

Per results of a Google search, I checked settings for VT-x/AMD-V (already enabled) and I/O APIC (enabled it but same result).

What am I missing?

Comment: Information about the host hardware is required.  Did you select Ubuntu 64-bit ( or can you select any 64-bit version ) when you created the virtual machine?  This problem normally comes from the fact you have Hyper-V installed.  Have you made sure that Windows actually knows your virtualization extensions are enabled?

Comment: @Ramhound Ah! the relevant setting is the version 'Ubuntu (64 bit)' when creating the VM, I hadn't noticed because it defaulted to plain 'Ubuntu' based on the VM name. Works now, thanks!

Comment: @rwallace yeah, i used to burn myself too with this. If creating the machine and naming it something with `64` in it, it will default to 64bit. Otherwise you need to select it yourself. (If you named it `Ubuntu (64bit)` from the beginning it would have defaulted to 64bit but i guess you just named it `Ubuntu`:)

Comment: @rwallace - Feel free to answer this question yourself.  I won't do it because my comment is based on multiple existing answers on this very website.

Answer (score 3):

I created my virtual machine when VT-x was disabled in BIOS.  So what happened is, it only let me pick non x64 OS versions.  I tried to boot the x64 image and got an error about VT-x not being  enabled.  Went in to BIOS and turned it on (why is the default off Asus?!).   Tried to boot again and got another error.  After reading this post I went back into the settings and saw that the OS version drop down now included x64 entries. After selecting one of those, it booted right up.

Comment: It's off by default for security reasons

Comment: Can you elaborate? I assume so that some rouge boot loader can not root the box?  Seems unlikely, especially with secure boot.

Comment: I don't know the specifics of it, but remember that Secure Boot is only ONE avenue of safety (if you are only talking about those attacks). But I was simply told that was the issue, so that's what I went off of. Intel disables it by default on desktop boards as well